# Turn off wifi on RINGING phone state

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I'm developing an application in which the wifi state goes OFF when the phonestate is RINGING.

My code is as follows :

phonestateManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phone.state"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".PhonestateActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    
        <activity android:name=".WifitoggleActivity" />    
        <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" />
    </application>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

PhonestateActivity.java

```
public class PhonestateActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PhonestateActivity.this,
                        ServiceReceiver.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ServiceReceiver.java

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager);
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, MyPhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

MyPhoneStateListener.java

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private WifitoggleActivity ss;

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
            ss = new WifitoggleActivity();
            Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WifitoggleActivity.java

```
public class WifitoggleActivity extends Activity {
    public WifitoggleActivity() {
        System.out.print("INSIDE WIFI");
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        } else {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is just FORCE CLOSEing in my device. Is it a problem with the Manifest file?

Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: If you need guidance then we are here to help.Nobody has time to read all this code.Be specific.You are new to community so remember for future.I will be helpful to you also.Can you post your log cat

Comment: sure Sir.........as u said,im new to this community....i wil post my logcat

Comment: post your log cat,it will help to identify the error easily

Comment: 11-22 16:52:41.200: D/AndroidRuntime(270): Shutting down VM
11-22 16:52:41.200: W/dalvikvm(270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.phone.state/com.phone.state.ServiceReceiver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)

Comment: 11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at com.phone.state.PhonestateActivity$1.onClick(PhonestateActivity.java:22)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)

Comment: 11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 16:52:41.229: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

Comment: Check answer , i have identified your problem.If it solved then mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver not an Activity.  You are using wrong code in first block.

Find the onClick handler in your code:

```
public class PhonestateActivity extends Activity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

Then remove these two lines:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(PhonestateActivity.this,ServiceReceiver.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

**and replace them by**

```
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
        registerReceiver(new ServiceReceiver(),intentFilter);
```

As ServiceReceiver is not an activity.

**Edited**

Add one more permission:

```
 android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

and change

```
  <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name=" android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />  
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Now remove two line that registering broadcast from oncreate method
[Check this link](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)

Comment: ya i changed ,but the application is directly sending the Broadcast without the UI...can u pls check the manifest file,if there is any mismatch in the permissions.....